# Which thread does the block in dispatch_once run in?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Which thread does the block in dispatch_once run in?
Can dispatch_once block run in background thread if the code is run from main thread? How do I ensure it runs on the main thread regardless of which thread executes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It runs in the current/calling thread. If you wanted I suppose you could use `dispatch_sync` to ensure it runs on a background thread but I'm not sure what that'd get you. In sum, it runs in the current thread. If another thread is already in the `dispatch_once` block, the calling thread will block until the block finishes executing on the other thread, and then proceed.

Comment: As of iOS 8/Yosemite, `dispatch_once` will also make sure that the thread actually executing the block will run at the highest QoS (~priority) among all of the other threads waiting in the same `dispatch_once` for the block to finish.

Comment: The best way to ensure that is to only ever call this API from the main thread, and at that point you don't need `dispatch_once` any more. There's really no other way to get this right. The most obvious problem looks like this: your BG thread hits the `dispatch_once`, then the main thread also hits it; main thread will be blocked waiting for the BG thread to exit the block, but the BG thread will be blocked waiting for the main thread to do the work and return. Hence deadlock.

Comment: actually `dispatch_sync` doesn't change thread. You should use `dispatch_async` to change thread.